# System.MissingMethodException Constructor on type xxx not found

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, dbcontext, activator

I have a `generic method`, this method will receive a `dbcontext` type.
This generic method should create a new instance from the received context type and return it.

**a Dbcontext example:**

```
  class SchoolContext:DbContext
    {

        public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> dbContextOptions):base(dbContextOptions)
        {
            
        }

        public DbSet<Branche> Branches { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

**What i tried:**

```
public static TContext GetInstance<TContext>(string connectionString) where TContext:DbContext
{
    var      optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    TContext context = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TContext), optionsBuilder.Options) as TContext;

    return context;
}
```

**Erros I got :**

```
 System.MissingMethodException: 'Constructor on type 'SchoolContext' not found.'
```

**so please how I can fix this issue ?**

Comment: What is the solution you suggest sir and thas for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there.  You just need to start with a `DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>` to create a `DbContextOptions<SchoolContext>` for the constructor, like this:

```
public static TContext GetInstance<TContext>(string connectionString) where TContext : DbContext
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    TContext context = (TContext)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TContext), optionsBuilder.Options);

    return context;
}
```

Comment: Massive thanks sir, this answer helped me

Answer (score 0):

This isn't generic:

`var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();`

So this can't be generic either:

`optionsBuilder.Options`

So if you have a constructor that requires a specific generic type as an argument:
`public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> dbContextOptions)`

...then that means you're not passing what this constructor expects. So `Activator.CreateInstance` is looking for a constructor that takes whatever `optionsBuilder.Options` is (non-generic options), but it can't find one. That's the missing method.

You'll need to figure out how to create an instance of `DbContextOptions<SchoolContext>`.

If you change this

`var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();`

to

`var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SchoolContext>();`

then the `Options` property will return the generic type you need, `DbContextOptions<SchoolContext>`.

Comment: Massive thanks sir for your answer, you have all right and this fixed my issue