# Invoking a method with EF core dbContext to test with dummy data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I want to test a method (GetProjectInfo) from "AppManager" class using invoke,

AppManager.cs is as follows

> ```
> public AppManager(Configuration configuration,
>             AppClient client,
>             Manager _manager,
>             TicketCreator ticketCreator,
>             EmailCatalog emailCatalogConfig,
>             CommonConfiguration commonConfiguration,
>             Entities entities,
>             IBackgroundJobClient jobClient,
>             FMSManager fmsManager)
>         {
>             _configuration = configuration;
>             _manager = manager;
>             _ticketCreator = ticketCreator;
>             _commonConfiguration = commonConfiguration;
>             _entities = entities;
>             _jobClient = jobClient;
>             _emailCatalogConfig = emailCatalogConfig;
>             _client = client;
>             _client.SetAuthenticationToken(GetAuthenticationToken());
>             _fmsManager = fmsManager;
>         }
> ```

In above class, Entities is nothing but a DBcontext EF core class,

> ```
>  public partial class Entities : DbContext
>     {
>
>         public Entities()
>         {
>         }
>
>         public Entities(DbContextOptions<Entities> options)
>             : base(options)
>         {
>         }
>       
> .......All  DbSet properties
> .......OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
> ```

So to test/invoke this method I have created a console app with below code

> ```
>  static async Task Main(string[] args)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
>
>             Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("dll path");
>             Type type = assembly.GetType("AppManager");
>
>             MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("GetProjectInfo");
>
>             ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
>             object[] parametersArray = new object[] { "939f378161c42d85658fb2d77f497e0f" };
>
>             **var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Entities>()
>                            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "db_name")
>                            .Options;
>             Entities _entities = new Entities(options);**
>
>             object[] contructorArray = new object[] { null, null, null, null, null, null, _entities, null, null };
>
>             object result = null;
>
>             object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, contructorArray);
>
>             result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray);
> ```

So to invoke the method from AppManager class I need to pass Entities to constructor param which I did as heighted bold above. But with this I am not able to connect to db.

Error I am getting here is,

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Constructor on type 'AppManager' not
> found.'

The method I want to test here is, it has _client from AppManager DI.

```
>  public Project GetProjectInfo(string id)
>         {
>             using (Entities _entities = new Entities())
>             {
>                 Project _project = null;
>                 RetryMechanism(() => { _project = _client.GetProjectInfo(id); }, retryPhraseAppClient);
>                 return _project;
>                 //return _client.GetProjectInfo(id);
>             }
> 
>         }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.MissingMethodException Constructor on type xxx not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162079/system-missingmethodexception-constructor-on-type-xxx-not-found)

Comment: "I want to test a method (GetProjectInfo) from "AppManager" class using invoke" Why? since you need to know how to call the constructor, why do you think you need to use reflection?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman may be I put it in wrong way, I just simply wanted to test  method GetProjectInfo with invoke with some dummy data. It has _client, _entities  from AppManager DI. How can I do it? Any other suggestion?

Comment: `Assembly.LoadFile("dll path");` So a 3rd party is providing an assembly at runtime? And this assembly is using DI? Then you need some contract for the 3rd party to implement, as a factory method. Is this 3rd party going to have access to your assembly? Then I would define `GetProjectInfo` as an interface member that they are supposed to implement. Similarly `AppManager` should implement an interface, and I would obtain an instance via some other contract. Perhaps by looking for a `CreateHostBuilder` method. No need for reflection.